# Meta tag in css content: ''; property

Tags: html, css

I have a bit weird task so I have to ask you weird question.
I have meta tag:

```
<meta content="Joe Gelb" name="username" />
```

and I need to push it right in css with content attribute as I think. I tried something like that:

```
content: attr(meta[name="username"]);
```

and

```
content: string(meta[name="username"]);
```

but it doesnt work. Help pls)

Comment: you cannot do this

Comment: `meta` tags are not shown in the browser's view. Why do you think influencing it in CSS will do anything? Where would you style them?